# program only read last line in .txt file java

Tags: java

I have a problem and don't know what to do. This method is supposed to read all the text in a .txt document. My problem is when the document contains more then one line of text and the program only read the last line. The program don't need to worry about signs like . , : or spaces, but it have to read all the letters. Can anybody help me?

example text

hello my name is 
(returns the right result)

hello my

name is

(returns only name is)

```
private Scanner x;
String readFile(String fileName)
{
  try {
    x = new Scanner (new File(fileName + (".txt")));
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("cant open file");
  }
  while (x.hasNext()) {
    read = x.next(); 
  } 
  return read;
}
```

Comment: `read += x.next(); ` or `read += x.next() + "\n"; ` It's the `+=` that matters here since it concatenates the current String with the new String. A purist will tell you to use a StringBuilder or StringBuffer since this involves the creation of fewer objects, and is thus usually more efficient, but this really doesn't matter for a small amount of data.

Comment: Your program is reading everything, in side the while loop, but you just discard all values but the last; you can just add all the lines into a string (preferably using a StringBuffer or such).

Comment: Also, for actual use instead of learning, you can use readAllBytes or readAllLines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you use `read = x.next()`, the string in the `read` object is always being replaced by the text in the next line of the file. Use `read += x.next()` or `read = read.concat(x.next());` instead.

Comment: This works. But do you know how I can turn it into one line after I've read it?  read.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""); does not work

Comment: Are you using the example text above (hello my<newline>name is)? Also what is the result when you use `replaceAll`?

Comment: I'm using secret <newline> text. then I run this   
   for (int i=0;i<read.length();i++) {
      encrypted+= ((char)(read).charAt(i)+13)); 
 I put this into a new document, read the new file do the opposite and put that into a third document. my third document always read
 secret <newline> text <newline> ?                              so I thought if I make an ordenary string without any lines or anything that would fix the problem

Comment: Are you doing `read = read.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");`? Notice that the `read` object is to the left of the `=` operator, since strings are immutable in Java; simply calling `read.replaceAll` will not modify the original `String` object in any way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030872/reading-encrypting-writing-reading-dekrypting-and-writing-again-java  its kind of complicated

Answer (score 1):

You replace every read with every `read()`. Also, you didn't `close()` your `Scanner`. I would use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and something like,

```
String readFile(String fileName)
{
  String read = "";
  try (Scanner x = new Scanner (new File(fileName + (".txt")));) {
    while (x.hasNextLine()) {
      read += x.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator(); // <-- +=
    } 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("cant open file");
  }
  return read;
}
```

Comment: Scanner is an `AutoCloseable` object?

Comment: @Unihedron [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is `Closeable`. And, *Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable*

Comment: Thanks, TIL! Would upvote for wise use, but I'm out of votes for today.